# How to set json model with array of data returned from function

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have a sapui5 application:

I have an xml view called "Submission.view and corresponding controller called "submission.controller".

I have method which is fetching some question id's from a service using certain input parameters.

For example if i pass "null" and "previous" it gives me a json response as:

```
[
{
        "__type__": "QuestionOutput",
        "QuestionType": "",
        "QuestionID": 51,
        "YesNo": "",
        "Mandatory": false
    },
    {
        "__type__": "QuestionOutput",
        "QuestionType": "",
        "QuestionID": 52,
        "YesNo": "",
        "Mandatory": false
    },
    {
        "__type__": "QuestionOutput",
        "QuestionType": "",
        "QuestionID": 53,
        "YesNo": "",
        "Mandatory": false
    }
]
```

Now i want to pass each of the questionid's like 51,52,53 to another method which calls a rest service to fetch the descriptions for the above questionid's from hana data base.

```
getBpmRules: function(sToken, sQuestionId, sAnswer) {
        var that = this;

        this.showBusy();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            url: "/bpmrulesruntime/rules-service/v1/rules/invoke?rule_service_name=SelfServiceRule::QuestionRuleService",
            context: that,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': sToken
            },
            data: JSON.stringify([{
                "__type__": "QuestionInput",
                "QuestionID": "" + sQuestionId + "",
                "Answer": "" + sAnswer + ""
            }]),

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                that.hideBusy();
                sap.m.MessageBox.alert(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown + " : " + jqXHR.responseText, {
                    icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,
                    title: this.getText("error")
                });
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var questiondesc = [];

                if (data.length !== 0) {
                    var desc = [];
                    //this.getModel("questionModel").setProperty("/questionDescription", data);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        desc = that.getQuestionDescriptionById(data[i].Question, sToken);

                    }
                }

                that.hideBusy();
                this._oManagerBusy.setVisible(false);
                this._showSendDialog();

            }
        });
    }
```

After getting the json data i am just looping and passing the question ids to another method to get the description for each question which again is a json response.

```
getQuestionDescriptionById: function(id, token) {
        jQuery.sap.log.debug("Getting question by Id");
        var questionDescription = [];
        this.getComponent().ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/selfservice/rest/question/admin/questionid/" + id,

            contentType: "application/json",
            context: this,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': token
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                this.getModel("resources").setProperty("/ticketSubmitMessage", this.getModel("i18n").getProperty("sendDialogText"));
                this._oManagerBusy.setVisible(false);
                this._showSendDialog();
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //oModel.loadData(“json/Item.json”);
                //  this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(data.question,"questionDescription"));

                if (data.length !== 0) {

                    questionDescription.push(data);

                }

            }

        });
        return questionDescription;
    },
```

Issue:

I am not able to set the model for the view with the json response that i am getting from the second method since for each questionid it goes to the next method "getQuestionDescriptionById" and even though i return the response..it doesn't work.

Can you please let me know how to set a json model for each response that i get for each question id.

Thanks !!

Comment: getQuestionDescriptionById returns an empty array long before the async success handler is triggered.  Whatever action you are expecting to do with the populated array should be called from the success handler.